# Confused about Chain Rule on Smooth Manifolds

Tags: derivatives, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, chain-rule, smooth-functions

So Lee's smooth manifolds defines the chain rule on functions between manifolds as:

$$d(F\circ G)=dF\circ dG$$

Where $F:M\rightarrow N$ and $G:N\rightarrow L$ where $M,N$ and $L$ are smooth manifolds. However, I do not see how this reduces to the "classic" chain rule on $\mathbb{R}$ that we all know and love. If we let $M=N=L=\mathbb{R}$ then how does the above line reduce to:
$$\frac{d}{dx}(F\circ G)=(\frac{d}{dx}F\circ G)\frac{d}{dx}G$$
Or since I'm not sure notationally thats correct:
$$\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x))=f'(g(x))g'(x)$$
I cannot see how these two are equivalent, though I'm honestly assuming I have gotten lost in the notation and don't really understand what $dF$ is.

Comment: For a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, can you describe what the differential $df$ is, starting from the definition?

Comment: I assume you meant to write $G: M \to N$ and $F : N \to L$, or the composition makes no sense. Then, if you are satisfied with thinking of the differential $df_p$ of $f$ at $p$ for some smooth $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ as $\frac{d}{dx}\vert_p f = f'(p)$, try showing that for $p \in M$ you have that $d(F \circ G)_p = dF_{G(p)} \circ dG_p$. Use that the restriction of $dG$ to $T_pM$ is equal to $dG_p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chain rule is

$$
d(f\circ g)_p=df_{g(p)}\circ dg_p
$$

This is exactly the same if $M=\mathbb{R}^m$ and $N=\mathbb{R}^n$, but in this case we generally use a different notation as

$$
\partial (f\circ g)(p)=(\partial f\circ g)(p)\circ \partial g(p)
$$

As the derivatives at a point are linear we generally just write the composition of linear maps by yuxtaposition, given

$$
\partial (f\circ g)(p)=(\partial f\circ g)(p)\partial g(p)
$$

or

$$
d(f\circ g)_p=df_{g(p)} dg_p
$$

Above $\partial f$ represent the Fréchet derivative of $f$.

Comment: Are you saying that because the derivatives at a point are linear it reduces to multiplication? I don't really follow your argument here